# Is there a way to control children hairs so they don't cut through a mesh?

Tags: mesh, particles

I need to have the children hairs spread out so that it covers the hea, unfortunately this causes the problem of the children hairs not following the mesh it is on and cutting through the mesh, unrealistically.

Comment: Please post screenshots and/or your blend file if possible.

Answer (score 2):

**Try using *interpolated* children instead of *simple*.**

Interpolated children are interpolated across the surface of the mesh between the parents. Simple children, on the other hand, are just placed in space around the parents.

Here is a comparison of simple vs. interpolated (click to enlarge):
[image]

The left two planes are using simple children, the right two are using interpolated.  You can see how the simple children are hovering in mid-air, poking through the mesh, and not evenly spaced.  While the interpolated children stay on the surface of the mesh and are more evenly distributed.

Comment: I am using interpolated. I think my problem is that I have 1000 hairs on the head total, and the bangs part (The part that cuts through the head) has 300 parents when it doesn't need 300.

Comment: @MarcusMravik Hmm... that's interesting.  If you upload your .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and post the link in your question I can take a look and see if I can determine the problem.

Comment: The file was too big to go onto Blend Exchange so here is the shared .Blend file from my One Drive https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=be95339348ec8314!30332&authkey=!AHh6u6zOCRFY9F0&ithint=file%2cblend1